# Can't Disable Turboboost

Tags: windows-10, laptop, cpu

I have an Intel i7 4710-mq in my laptop. Due to thermal issues, I have set the maximum processor state to 99% so as to avoid Intel Turbo Boost kicking in. However, this does not appear to be working.

After several minutes of gaming, the laptop hits the tj max and shuts down.

There is no evident throttling of the CPU prior to this happening so I have no idea why Turbo Boost isn't being disabled (there is no option to do so in the BIOS) or why thermal throttling doesn't appear to be occuring.

Any advice on how to resolve these issues would be appreciated.

Comment: There should be an option within the firmware, if there is no option within the devices hardware, then it cannot be disabled.

Comment: I've checked the BIOS and there are no options there, however, several posts online have suggested that the 99% max processor state should disable it. If you don't know about that, any idea why thermal throttling isn't kicking in?

Comment: Why not correct the causes of your "thermal issues" instead of trying to down-clock?

Comment: I don't see how limiting the base frequency would have any effect on if the TurboBoost was enabled or not.  Turboboost is how much additional frequency past the base frequency the CPU can ran at, so if you limit your base frequency to 99%, that only means you run 1% below the maximum frequency it can ran at with Turboboost

Comment: I got the feeling that you are not trying to solve a root problem but instead are looking for a workaround. While that may or may not work, the laptop should just work without any tricks. If not it is broken, the fan is clogged or similar. Fix that instead.

Comment: I've cleaned out the fan, reapplied thermal paste and all of the usual. It appears to have only become a problem since I upgraded to Windows 10

Comment: A laptop is designed to work with Turboboost enabled, and it it designed so it will not overheat, so if its overheating you should address the reason its overheating.  Running intensive software should not be enough to cause your laptop to overheat.

Comment: It idles at around 60C, have you guys got any suggestions of what to try if you don't think software is the issue? Either way, shouldn't the CPU start throttling down as it approaches the tj max to keep temps safe?

Comment: clean the CPU fan from dust and look if this lower the temperature

Comment: @magicandre1981 I've already done that, made next to no difference

Comment: if you're out of warrenty, open the laptop and replace the cpu thermal paste. better paste can also lower the temperature